# The launch shell script using alt+f2 (debian/mate)

Tags: linux, shell, symlink

I have script for run app

```
#!/bin/bash
wine /opt/winbox.exe
```

folder for it

```
/home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh
```

I created symlink for it

```
sudo ln -s /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh /usr/local/bin/winbox
```

but after run

```
alt+f2 --> winbox
```

i have error

```
Error when getting information for file '/home/myuser/winbox': No such file or directory
```

where I make a mistake and how to run the script using alt+f2?

Comment: make sure winbox is executable and readable: `sudo chmod a+x+r /usr/local/bin/winbox`, in addition to being in your `$PATH` (`/usr/local/bin` usually is, so that should be taken care of)

Comment: yep, i forgot about permission for winbox-script: sudo chmod u+x /home/myuser/scripts/winbox.sh. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem. Set directive with gksudo dialog

```js
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>~/winbox.log
set -x
sh -c "gksudo wine /opt/winbox/winbox.exe"
```